# Temporal Tables Between Clause - Rows are included that shouldn't be?

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have a SQL Server 2016 temporal table. I executed a query which can be seen below, along with the results. I'm curious why the row highlighted in green is included. The ValidFrom value occurs before the begin date of '7/12/2018 19:16:00' and the ValidTo occurs after the end date of '7/12/2018 19:30:00'.

My understanding of BETWEEN / AND, which might be incorrect, is that it finds all rows modified between two points in time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BETWEEN clause on a temporal table shows those rows that were active during the selected timeframe.  In more conventional terms, the rows that meet this criteria set:

```
WHERE StartTime <= <EndDateTime> 
    AND EndTime > <StartDateTime>
```

As you can see, this does not require an actual time stamp to fall within your BETWEEN dates.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I misunderstood what BETWEEN does. Are you aware of a built in way of determining what rows where changed during a range of dates?

Comment: Look at comparing just the ValidFrom in a normal query with the FOR SYSTEM TIME ALL condition, something like `WHERE ValidFrom BETWEEN @MyStart and @MyEnd FOR SYSTEM TIME ALL`

Comment: Hm. An update. You also want to check where ValidTo is in your range, and UNION the output rows. This would handle row deletions correctly.

Comment: Finally, if you have a range to look at, you could use your original query and add the WHERE on ValidFrom or ValidTo as well. This would be more efficient, so using your original query, add `WHERE ValidFrom BETWEEN @Start and @End OR ValidTo BETWEEN @Start and @End.`